# Functions being ignored inside else if block

Tags: c, string, function, if-statement

I have been trying to write a code to reverse a string in c code in Visual Studio. I am actually making a menu-driven program where the user can decide whether they want to input individual characters or a string with spaces. The problem is whenever they select the second option, no function works. As if it just glides through. Please check the code below:

```
/*
Question:
Develop and implement a function that receives some string value as a parameter and reverses it.
In the implementation, you cannot use any special functions from external string libraries.
*/


#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS     // Removes secure warnings
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
# define size 20

void reverse(char* a); //function for reversing string
int len(char* a); // function for finding the length of string


void reverse(char* a) //function for reversing string
{
    int i = 0, length_string;
    char tmp;

    length_string = len(a);
    printf(" \n\n\tThe length of the string is = %d\n", length_string);

    while (i < (length_string)) //reversing the array.......
    {
        tmp = *(a + length_string - 1);
        *(a + length_string - 1) = *(a + i);
        *(a + i) = tmp;
        i++;
        length_string--;
    }

}

int len(char* a) // function for finding the length of string
{
    int len = 0, k;
    for (k = 0; *(a + k) != '\0'; k++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char Answer;

    printf("\n\t==========Welcome to Reverse string function==========\n");
    printf("\n\tWhat kind of input would you like to give the Console?:\n\t\ta) Individual Characters\n\t\tb) Stream of Characters/String/Line\n ");
    printf("Answer (a or b ?) : ");
    scanf_s("%c", &Answer);

    switch (Answer) {
    case 'a':
    {
        printf("\n\t==========Welcome to Reverse string function==========\n");

        int i, char_num;
        printf("\n\tHOW many characters do you want to input: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &char_num);

        char* Input_char = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * char_num);

        if (Input_char == NULL) // if empty array
        {
            printf("\n\nError! Memory not allocated\n");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("\n");

        for (i = 0; i < char_num; i++)
        {
            printf("Please Enter one character : ");
            scanf(" %c", (Input_char + i));

        }
        printf("\n\nThe reversed Character Stream is :  ");


        for (i = 0; i < char_num; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", *(Input_char + char_num - i - 1));

        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("\n\t=====================End of Function=================\n\n");

        free(Input_char);
        break;
    }
    case 'b':
    {
    char Input_string[size];

    printf("\n\tEnter a string (It can also be a line :) ) : ");
    //gets_s(Input_string); // We can also use scanf, but in that case we can not take a blank space as input


    fgets(Input_string, size, stdin);

    reverse(Input_string); // Will call the function to reverse the string

    printf("\n\n\tThe reversed string is : ");
    printf("%s\n\n", Input_string);

    printf("\n\t=====================End of Function=================\n\n");
    }

                              }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem is in `scanf()`, it leaves a trailing newline in the stream which is later consumed by `fgets()`.

Comment: For **this example**, call `getchar()` right before `fgets()`.

Comment: Given that your `b` option is simple and straightforward [you would still need to strip the newline `fgets` will leave in buffer], what is the purpose of the more complicated `a` option? Also, I'm not sure your `reverse` is correct

Comment: There's no `else` in this code. Please revise the title (or check you posted the code you intended to post)

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function (option `a`) is a bit convoluted.

Your option `b` doesn't strip the newline left by `fgets`.

Your `reverse` uses:

```
*(a + length_string - 1)
```

This should be:

```
*(a + length_string - 1 - i)
```

The code can be simplified. The `reverse` function can find the the end of the string itself.

String reversal is a bit simpler using pointers.

Here's some refactored code:

```
/*
Question:
Develop and implement a function that receives some string value as a parameter and reverses it.
In the implementation, you cannot use any special functions from external string libraries.
*/

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS         // Removes secure warnings
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 20

// function for reversing string
void
reverse(char *a)
{
    char tmp;

    // find end of string
    char *b = a;
    for (;  *b != 0;  ++b);

    // point to last char
    --b;

    // reversing the array.......
    for (;  a < b;  ++a, --b) {
        tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
    }
}

int
main()
{
    char *cp;
    char Input_string[size];

    printf("\n\tEnter a string (It can also be a line :) ) : ");
    // We can also use scanf, but in that case we can not take a blank space
    // as input
    // gets_s(Input_string);

    cp = fgets(Input_string, size, stdin);
    if (cp != NULL) {
        // strip newline
        for (;  *cp != 0;  ++cp) {
            if (*cp == '\n') {
                *cp = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Will call the function to reverse the string
        reverse(Input_string);

        printf("\n\n\tThe reversed string is : ");
        printf("%s\n\n", Input_string);
    }

    printf("\n\t=====================End of Function=================\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```